# What defines an Almana?

Tags: halacha, women, marriage, halacha-theory

I was learning with a Rabbi today and we came across the following question. An Almana, widow, is not allowed to be married to a Kohen Gadol (see Mishna Yevamos 9:2). However, what defines a widow? Meaning, if the woman was married, had biah with her husband, and then her husband dies, it's clear that because she is no longer a virgin, [she can't marry the Kohen Gadol](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17941/2699).  But suppose the man dies without having biah with his wife: Do we say that this woman cannot marry a Kohen Gadol because she is an Almana(in the simple sense that she was married then her husband die), or is it necessary that she have had biah with her husband before he died that would label her an Almana and ultimately, unable to marry the Kohen Gadol?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3741/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The mishna in [*Y'vamos*](http://mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h31.htm) (6:4) indicates that a widow is forbidden to a Kohein Gadol whether she was a widow only from [*erusin*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erusin) (when intimacy was still forbidden) or whether she was a widow even from [*nisu'in*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_wedding):

> כוהן גדול לא יישא את האלמנה--בין אלמנה מן האירוסין בין אלמנה מן הנשואין.

This is quoted as *halacha* by the Rambam (*Hil. Isurei Bi'ah* [17:11](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=5&hilchos=27&perek=17&halocha=11)):

> אלמנה בין מן האירוסין בין מן הנישואין אסורה.

Both types of widow are biblically forbidden to a Kohein Gadol. A widow from either *erusin* or *nisu'in* is forbidden to a Kohein Gadol due to a negative prohibition ([*Vayikra* 21:14](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0321.htm#14), אַלְמָנָה... לֹא יִקָּח), and a widow from *nisu'in* is additionally forbidden due to a positive commandment (*Vayikra* 21:13, וְהוּא אִשָּׁה בִבְתוּלֶיהָ יִקָּח; *Sanhedrin* [18b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=18b&format=text)-[19a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=19&format=text); Rashi ibid. 18b, s.v. *ka pasik v'tani*; *Sefer HaChinuch* §273, or [§294](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40631&st=&pgnum=376) in some versions).

The gemara indicates that the definition of *almana* (widow) for this purpose should obviously include an *almana* from *erusin* ([*Y'vamos* 59a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=14&daf=59&format=text); Rashi ad loc., s.v. *p'shita*). However, since the prime example of an *almana* in the Pentateuch is Tamar ([*B'reishis* 38:11](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0138.htm#11)), who was a widow from *nisu'in*, the mishna had to clarify that the term *almana* indeed includes even widows from *erusin*.

The gemara comments that, notwithstanding the example of Tamar, the parameters of the *almana* status vis-à-vis a Kohein Gadol are derived from the parameters of the *g'rusha* (divorcee) status vis-à-vis a Kohein; just as "*g'rusha*" is defined to include divorcees from *erusin* or *nisu'in*, so is "*almana*" defined to include widows from *erusin* or *nisu'in* (*Y'vamos* 59a; see Rashi ad loc. s.v. *dumya d'grusha*).

Answer (score 1):

From a *drush* perspective, the gemara in  [Kesuvos 10b](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.10b.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he) expounds upon the meaning of the word "***almanah***":

> מאי אלמנה אמר רב חנא בגדתאה אלמנה על שם מנה
>
> Why [is a widow called an] *almanah*? Rav Ḥana of Baghdad said: [A widow is called an] *almanah* after the *maneh*

Namely, "***almanah***" is an acronym for "***al shem  maneh***"- ie the value of a widow's Kesuvah is worth a "***maneh***" (one hundred dinars).

Comment: had i known you knew i would have tagged you your own answer,,,

Comment: @user15464 