# Why isn't a divorced woman mentioned in the first mishna of Maseches Kesuvos?

Tags: talmud-gemara, marriage, divorce, maseches-kesubos

Maseches Kesuvos [2a](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.2a.1?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) begins with:

> בתולה נשאת ליום הרביעי ואלמנה ליום החמישי
>
> A virgin is married on Wednesday and a widow on Thursday.

The ensuing dafim tell us the reasons why these days were specifically singled out (ex: in case husband has a *ta'anas b'sulim, *shakdu*, the day that fish were created etc)

Why isn't a divorced woman (or even *yevamah*) mentioned in this Mishnah as well?

Comment: They have their own locations?

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel what do you mean?

Comment: My thought is that a divorced woman isn't mentioned because the reason given for a virgin doesn't apply to her: שאם היה לו טענת בתולים היה משכים לבית דין. Of course this wouldn't apply to a divorced woman. I'm not sure if this is contradicted by something on the ensuing dapim

Comment: @ba right- but the subsequent 2 would. Maybe one could suggest that she'd have the same *din* as a widow, but haven't seen a source that suggests that

Comment: In many places in shas we mention an almanah even though we really mean to include a divorcee. The point is a woman who isn't a besulah anymore.

Comment: @Rafael can you provide other instances please?

Comment: @alicht, look at the first mishnah in perek af al pi, we say an almanah gets 100 zuz for a kesubah. A gerusha gets the same, but it's not mentioned because it's really included.

Answer (score 2):

In [Kesubos 10b](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.10b.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi) the Gemorah defines exactly what *almanah* in the Mishana is referring to:

> מאי אלמנה אמר רב חנא בגדתאה אל**מנה** על שם **מנה** אלמנה מן האירוסין מאי איכא למימר איידי דהא קרי לה אלמנה הא נמי קרי לה אלמנה
>   What is an *Al**manah***? Says Rav Chono from bagdad: Her name means she gets a **Maneh**. -This would apply to a widow that consumated her marrage (rashi)- but a widow who was betrothed and still a virgin surely she gets *two* maneh? since we have coined a term for a widow from full mariage as "almana" we also use this term for a widow from betrothal (even though the name one *Maneh* does not reflect her value as vrgin to receive two *maneh* in her *Kesubah*)

So really there are only two categories:

1. a virgin who receives 2 maneh which include a regular newlywed, a widow from betrothal, a Yevama from betrothal or a divorcee from betrothal.
2. a widow from full marriage *nissuin* receives 1 Maneh like her name *almanah*, a Yevama from *nissuin*, a divorcee from *nissuin* and any woman who is not a virgin.

Comment: Haha- I recently quoted that exact gemara in a separate answer! https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/101622/18474